# Count how many times a string occurs in a specific column

Tags: python, recursion, count, counter, frequency

I am trying to see how many times a string occurs in column 4. More specifically how much times a port number occurs in some Netflow data. There are thousands of ports so I'm not looking for anything specific other than recursion. I have already parsed into the column using the numbers after the colon and I want the code to check how much times that number occurs so the final output should print the number with how many times it occurred like so..

[OUTPUT]

```
Port: 80 found: 3 times.
Port: 53 found: 2 times.
Port: 21 found: 1 times.
```

[CODE]

```
import re


frequency = {}

file = open('/Users/rojeliomaestas/Desktop/nettest2.txt', 'r')

with open('/Users/rojeliomaestas/Desktop/nettest2.txt', 'r') as infile:    
    next(infile)
    for line in infile:
        data = line.split()[4].split(":")[1]
        text_string = file.read().lower()
        match_pattern = re.findall(data, text_string)


for word in match_pattern:
    count = frequency.get(word,0)
    frequency[word] = count + 1

frequency_list = frequency.keys()

for words in frequency_list:
    print ("port:", words,"found:", frequency[words], "times.")
```

[FILE]

```
Date first seen          Duration Proto      Src IP Addr:Port          Dst IP Addr:Port   Packets    Bytes Flows
2017-04-02 12:07:32.079     9.298 UDP            8.8.8.8:80 ->     205.166.231.250:8080     1      345     1
2017-04-02 12:08:32.079     9.298 TCP            8.8.8.8:53 ->     205.166.231.250:80       1       75     1
2017-04-02 12:08:32.079     9.298 TCP            8.8.8.8:80 ->     205.166.231.250:69       1      875     1
2017-04-02 12:08:32.079     9.298 TCP            8.8.8.8:53 ->     205.166.231.250:443      1      275     1
2017-04-02 12:08:32.079     9.298 UDP            8.8.8.8:80 ->     205.166.231.250:23       1      842     1
2017-04-02 12:08:32.079     9.298 TCP            8.8.8.8:21 ->     205.166.231.250:25       1      146     1
```

Comment: OK.  What is your question?

Comment: Incidentally, why are you used `file.read` *and* `for line in infile`?  That seems barking.

Comment: Also the final output loop should be:  `for port, count in d.items(): print("port:", port, "found:", count, "times.")`  - use `iteritems` if you are stuck on Python 2.7.

Comment: My question is how can the code count the number of times a string occurs in column[4] without actually having to specify what the string is it just looks for recursion of any string and gives a count along with what the string is.

Comment: @rogernm001 to count an occurence of something it will need some form of something to compare it to. (if that makes sense)

Comment: It should compare 1 line to all the other lines in the file and keep doing that until every line is compared and counted if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like:

```
frequency = {}
with open('/Users/rojeliomaestas/Desktop/nettest2.txt', 'r') as infile:    
    next(infile)
    for line in infile:
        port = line.split()[4].split(":")[1]
        frequency[port] = frequency.get(port,0) + 1

for port, count in frequency.items(): 
    print("port:", port, "found:", count, "times.")
```

The heart of this is that you keep a dict of port to count, and increment this for every line.  `dict.get` will return the current value or a default (in this case 0).

Comment: How would I sort this from most to least?

Comment: That's a separate question - and almost certainly a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

From python standard library. Will return a dictionary with exactly what you are looking for.

```
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(column)
counts.most_common(n) # will return the most common values for specified number (n)
```

Comment: Some more explanation would be useful here. I can't see, currently, how this answers the question (which isn't really a question, either).

Comment: Oh my gosh people my question is how can the code count the number of times a string occurs in a column[4] without actually having to specify what the string is it just looks for recursion of any string and gives a count.

Comment: It should compare 1 line to all the other lines in the file and keep doing that until every line is compared and counted if that makes sense?